# Converting dict to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How to convert below dict to dataframe?

```
{'Design':         id       text discipline
 0  des-345  Wonderful         md
 1  tni-982     Thanks         hw
 2  xpn-675      Enjoy         sw}
```

I tried `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ws.values())`. But get error as ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 3, 3).

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: that looks like a dict with a df as a value. Have you tried `d['Design']`?

Comment: it's not a `dict`,  it's a text table with curly brackets tagged onto the beginning and end

Answer (score 2):

- it's not really a `dict`. I have *fixed* it by inserting `"""` to mark start end and of text table, delimited by spaces
- this can then easily be used in `read_csv()`

```
d = {'Design':"""         id       text discipline
 0  des-345  Wonderful         md
 1  tni-982     Thanks         hw
 2  xpn-675      Enjoy         sw"""}

pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(d["Design"]),sep="\s+")
```

|  | id | text | discipline |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | des-345 | Wonderful | md |
| 1 | tni-982 | Thanks | hw |
| 2 | xpn-675 | Enjoy | sw |